# RHEL9: List dependencies of a "rpm" package with "dnf": I wish to see the Repo package name

Tags: rhel, rpm, dnf

List dependencies of a "rpm" package with "dnf".

```
dnf repoquery --requires java-17-openjdk-devel

Updating Subscription Management repositories.
(..)
/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/alternatives
java-17-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:17.0.2.0.8-13.el9
java-17-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:17.0.3.0.7-1.el9_0
java-17-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:17.0.4.0.8-2.el9_0
java-17-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:17.0.4.1.1-2.el9_0
java-17-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:17.0.4.1.1-5.el9
java-17-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:17.0.5.0.8-1.el9_1
java-17-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:17.0.5.0.8-2.el9_0
java-17-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:17.0.6.0.10-3.el9_1
java-17-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:17.0.7.0.7-1.el9_1
java-17-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:17.0.7.0.7-3.el9
java-17-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:17.0.8.0.7-2.el9
java-17-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:17.0.9.0.9-2.el9
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit)
libdl.so.2()(64bit)
libpthread.so.0()(64bit)
rtld(GNU_HASH)
```

I wish to see package name instead of `libc.so.6`. Which rpm package provides `libc.so.6` and all other outputed deps.

Comment: `dnf provides */libc.so.6` provides the packages (i686 & X86_64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try adding `--resolve`. Example on Fedora 38:

```shellsession
$ dnf repoquery --arch x86_64 --resolve --requires java-17-openjdk-devel
alternatives-0:1.25-1.fc38.x86_64
bash-0:5.2.21-1.fc38.x86_64
glibc-0:2.37-16.fc38.x86_64
java-17-openjdk-1:17.0.9.0.9-3.fc38.x86_64
```